# Implement Spring RESTful Web Services with OAuth2 - Save id token as id session

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've implemented Spring RESTful Web Services with OAuth2 in Spring Boot with id token:

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;


@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig {

    private static final String SERVER_RESOURCE_ID = "oauth2-server";
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceServerConfig.class);
    private static InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @Order(2)
    protected class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer");
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("HttpSecurity");
            http.anonymous().disable().
                requestMatchers().antMatchers("/v1/**").
                and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @Order(1)
    protected class AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer");
            endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore).approvalStoreDisabled();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer: {}", clients);
            clients.inMemory().withClient("client").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit", "client_credentials")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read").resourceIds(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID).secret("secret");
        }


    }
}
```

I'm using load balancer to route authentication and calls request, but id_token doesn't same between all servers since id_token is saved just in memory and when user calls an authentication has an id_token1 from server 1 and when calls a request perhaps the load balancer route to Server 2 and here doesn't exist id_token1. An opcion to solve this issue is using Redis (e.g) to save id_token, another option also can be using JWT. As I'm using WebSphere as server application  **I'd like use session id** to keep id_token across all servers, I don't think this could be a good idea but still I want implement this solution, have you got any ideas how could implement this solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You already know your two options. If your idea is to make the application stateless, I would suggest JWT. However, it comes with a price of adding extra security to JWT so that you don't expose your token as everything will be on the client side. One main advantage of using JWT is that you don't have to worry about additional server/resources that you'll need to provide to redis server.

Comment: I need use session_id instead two option I said.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do that? You could cluster your servers and use sticky session if you really have to do it.

Comment: Because of Enterprise's internal politics, they don't want to change id token instead JWT, so that I need use session id.